# How to set s:param value in Ajax success body in Struts 2

Tags: ajax, jsp, datatable, struts2

How can I set `<s:param>` value in Ajax success body?

I load a data with Ajax call and I fetch it into `datatable`
but when I want to set `s:param` value I can not get its value, below is my code:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "dataPp",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success: function (res) {
            table = $('table#dttable1').DataTable();
            table.clear();
            $.each(res.dokpp, function(i, item){
                var json = res.dokpp[i];
                table.row.add(
                    [json["kodeDok"],
                    json["fileNameUi"],
                    json["depPenerbit"],
                    json["createdDate"],
                    json["tglBerlaku"],
                    json["tglKadaluarsa"],
                    json["urutRev"],
                    '<s:url var="prev" namespace="/mr" action="prevDasboard">'+
                        '<s:param name="file">'+json["fileName"]+'</s:param>'+
                    '</s:url>'+
                    '<a href="${prev}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">preview</a>'
                ]);
                console.log(json["fileName"]);
            }); 
            table.draw();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with this code :

```
'<a href="mr/prevDasboard?file='+json["fileName"]+'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">preview</a>'
```

I use html tag to create a href.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `<s:param>` tag the value is not yet available.

Struts tags are executed on server when JSP is rendered, but ajax is a javascript code which is executed on the client's browser after response is returned from the server. The server can't know what the value is substituted by the client.

You can render url without parameter and then add it dynamically.

```
var url = '<s:url var="prev" namespace="/mr" action="prevDasboard"/>?file='+json["fileName"];
```